# Blazor: Calling Methods without including within ConfigureServices

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am new to Blazor and I can't find a straight answer/article on this.

I have a table generating from a DB table just fine; however, I am having to add: 
`services.AddSingleton<ListUserMaint>();` within my Startup.cs file.

I have seen where others are using an api route, for example: */api/ListUserMaint* but is there any other way to just call the controller directly? I am trying to keep my controllers separate and I don't want to have to add `services.AddSingleton<Controller>();` every time I have a new file.

Component:

```html
@page "/usermaint"
@using Rogue.Controllers
@using Rogue.Models.ViewModels

@inject ListUserMaint ListUsers


@if (users == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table table-hover table-md">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left tableHead d-none" id="userId">Id</th>
                <th class="text-left tableHead">CompanyName</th>
                <th class="text-left tableHead">User Name</th>
                <th class="text-left tableHead">First Name</th>
                <th class="text-left tableHead">Last Name</th>
                <th class="text-left tableHead">Title</th>
                <th class="text-left tableHead">City</th>
                <th class="text-left tableHead">State</th>
                <th class="text-left tableHead text-right">Remove</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var u in users)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@u.Id</td>
                    <td>@u.CompanyName</td>
                    <td>@u.UserName</td>
                    <td>@u.FirstName</td>
                    <td>@u.LastName</td>
                    <td>@u.Title</td>
                    <td>@u.City</td>
                    <td>@u.State</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="sqButton btnRed float-right">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private IEnumerable<ListUsersViewModel.User> users;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        users = await ListUsers.UserMaint();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```c#
namespace Rogue.Controllers
{
    public class ListUserMaint : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
        private ICompanyRepository companyRepository;

        //constructor
        public ListUserMaint(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ICompanyRepository companyRepository)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.companyRepository = companyRepository;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public async Task <IEnumerable<ListUsersViewModel.User>> UserMaint()
        {
            //Get users from ApplicationUser
            var users = await userManager.Users.ToListAsync();

            //Create a new model for the List View (It has been extended to include CompanyName
            var model = new ListUsersViewModel();

            foreach (var u in users)
            {
                //Store this information into the List View Model and get the Company Name in the process
                var userinfo = new ListUsersViewModel.User
                {
                    UserName = u.UserName,
                    Id = u.Id,
                    FirstName = u.FirstName,
                    LastName = u.LastName,
                    Title = u.Title,
                    Email = u.Email,
                    CompanyId = u.CompanyId,
                    //CompanyName = u.Company.CompanyName,  //Extended via foreign key
                    City = u.City,
                    State = u.State
                };
                model.Users.Add(userinfo);
            };

            return model.Users;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a Controller for CRUD operations you don't have to inject it in the DI pipeline. You should just invoke your endpoint using an HttpClient, and parse your json result. You need to inject a class/service only if you need to use it directly from a component.

A good approach is to keep all of your controller in another project, server hosted, so you won't send all of your code for interacting with the db in the webassebly compiled code